# Python: How to break the loop if character limit is met?

Tags: python, loops

I am creating a string that must be exactly 140 characters long. I must use  a loop with a break statement, and the string items are taken from the given list.

In the end, I managed to get to 147 characters. Is there a way to truncate the string?

```
headlines = ["Local Bear Eaten by Man",
             "Legislature Announces New Laws",
             "Peasant Discovers Violence Inherent in System",
             "Cat Rescues Fireman Stuck in Tree",
             "Brave Knight Runs Away",
             "Papperbok Review: Totally Triffic"]

news_ticker = ""

for headline in headlines:
    if len(str(news_ticker)) >= 140:
        break
    else:
        news_ticker = list(news_ticker)
        news_ticker.append(headline)

print(news_ticker)
print(len(str(news_ticker)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
news_ticker = news_ticker[:140]
```

will truncate the string to 140 characters if that is what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer returns news_ticker as a list, but it needs to be a string.  It allows you to use the .append function, but you can simply concatenate the string like this:

```
for headline in headlines:
    news_ticker += headline + " "
    if len(news_ticker) >= 140:
        news_ticker = news_ticker[:140]
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
headlines = ["Local Bear Eaten by Man",
             "Legislature Announces New Laws",
             "Peasant Discovers Violence Inherent in System",
             "Cat Rescues Fireman Stuck in Tree",
             "Brave Knight Runs Away",
             "Papperbok Review: Totally Triffic"]

news_ticker = ""
for headline in headlines:
  news_ticker +=  headline + " "
  if len(news_ticker) >= 140:
    news_ticker = news_ticker[:140]
    break


print(news_ticker)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
news_ticker = ""
headlines = ["Local Bear Eaten by Man",
             "Legislature Announces New Laws",
             "Peasant Discovers Violence Inherent in System",
             "Cat Rescues Fireman Stuck in Tree",
             "Brave Knight Runs Away",
             "Papperbok Review: Totally Triffic"]
for headline in headlines:
    previous=news_ticker
    news_ticker = news_ticker + headline + " "
    #print(len(news_ticker))
    if len(news_ticker) >= 140:
        break
print(len(previous))
```

Comment: Welcome and thanks for posting an answer. It's always good practice to add some additional comments to your answer and why it solves the problem, rather than just posting a code snippet.